# What can i do to display the plotly graph in flask web page?

Tags: html, flask, plotly

Here's the code for my flask application. I want to display plotly graph in my webpage but it's not getting displayed.

python:

```
@trade.route('/',methods=["POST", "GET"])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
          symbol=str(request.form['symbol']).upper()
          if finnhub_client.company_profile2(symbol=symbol) == {} or symbol=='':
               flash('Invalid symbol!', category='error')
          information = dict(finnhub_client.company_profile2(symbol=symbol))

          url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol='+symbol+'&outputsize=full&apikey=HCWSV4D09YCJ1DKT'
          r = requests.get(url)
          data = r.json()

          date = data['Time Series (Daily)']
          high = [float(data['Time Series (Daily)'][x]['2. high']) for x in date]

          fig = px.line(data, x=data['Time Series (Daily)'].keys(), y=high, title='Time Series with Range Slider and Selectors', color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Set1)

          fig.update_xaxes(
          rangeslider_visible=False,
          rangeselector=dict(
               buttons=list([
                    dict(count=1, label="1m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(count=1, label="YTD", step="year", stepmode="todate"),
                    dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
                    dict(step="all")
               ])
          )
          )

          # Define the buttons first
          buttons = [
          dict(
               args=[{"yaxis.range": [min(high), max(high)]}],
               label="Full",
               method="relayout"
          ),
          dict(
               args=[{"yaxis.range": [min(high), max(high) * 0.75]}],
               label="75%",
               method="relayout"
          ),
          dict(
               args=[{"yaxis.range": [min(high), max(high) * 0.5]}],
               label="50%",
               method="relayout"
          ),
          dict(
               args=[{"yaxis.range": [min(high), max(high) * 0.25]}],
               label="25%",
               method="relayout"
          ),
          ]

          # Update the updatemenus with the defined buttons
          fig.update_layout(
          updatemenus=[dict(buttons=buttons, direction="down", showactive=True)]
          )

          return render_template("try.html",information=information,fig=fig)
```

html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content  %}
<div id='chart' class='chart'>hiiii</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var graphs = {{fig | safe}};
  Plotly.plot('chart',graphs,{});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

In the 'base.html' file I've added these scripts in head part :

```
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I'm getting error in html page :
Property assignment expected.
Declaration or statement expected.
',' expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the image in the static folder after its generated and use the img tag in html to fetch and display the image on the web page

Comment: I'm plotting a graph of real-time stock prices. in this case, the static image won't work